# EF Core and Visual Studio 2017: Add-Migration doesn't include new files into TFS source control

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

`Add-Migration` generates new files but doesn't include them into TFS source control - they are invisible for Check-in operation and are shown without lock sign on Solution Explorer.

Is there the way to solve it?

P.S. This all happens in project  `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` style. The question can be asked in more wide form: is there a way to "pick up" new files (created without Visual Studio) and include them to TFS automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the project/solution to source control? You need to add the solution to source control first, after that the new generated files will be detected automatically within the workspace.

Tested on my side and cannot reproduce this issue. Could you provide a sample project for further troubleshooting if that still not work?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes project is under source control... And it continue to work the same way (I need include new generated files to TFS using source control explorer).
I see that your projects are classic, when I use "standard"   Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" - may be this is a reason.

Comment: Actually problem with my SKD is logical - in classic project you was obligated to include all files with "add existed file"... Now I can ignore it - files are automatically included to solution (and include to tfs step is skipped). But still.. GIt works in this place without any problem.